# Не могу открыть порт

Tags: tcp, port, linksys

**Роутер: Linksys E1000**

Не могу открыть порт **2424**

Зарезервировал для компьютера статический ip
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил на него "переадресацию"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И разрешил соединение в брандмауэре
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но 2ip пишет, что порт закрыт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что я делаю не так?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Порт доступен в локальной сети и без дополнительных танцев с бубном. Просто(элементарно) сервер слушал localhost, а не 192.168.x.x

Answer (score 0):

Открой порт и по UDP, может поможет.
Еще провайдер может не разрешать обращаться к портам. Попробуй позвонить им.

Comment: Не получилось. И думаю дело не в провайдере. Я всего то хочу открыть порт в локальной сети

Comment: В локальной сети не нужно открывать порт, он и так должен быть доступен.

Comment: Должен. Но по адресам типа 192.168.x.x я не могу достучаться до сервера

Comment: А на компьютере, где запущен сервер я могу обратиться и к localhost и к его 192.168.x.x